# Como colocar campo de data no cadastro de um produto?

Tags: e-commerce

Estou precisando criar um modulo para o Prestashop onde no cadastro do produto terá que ter um novo campo date (Data de validade). Essa validade será usada para os produtos que são perecíveis.

Por acaso, alguém sabe como colocar um campo **data** no cadastro do produto?

Imagem:
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[Imagem com melhor qualidade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRahv.png)

Qualquer instrução será muito bem vinda.

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução seria você cadastrar o grupo de atributo "Data de validade" com os referidos valores e depois adicionar o atributo correspondente a cada produto onde se tornar necessário.

---

Você deve cadastrar o atributo, depois de cadastrado voltar à listagem, clicar no mesmo a fim de "entrar" nele e depois cadastrar um novo valor para o mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Entendi, sabe informar se o atributo fica visível apenas no Admin?

Comment: Ficam visíveis na loja também. Ao visualizar um produto específico, os atributos do produto aparecerão.

Comment: A necessidade dele é a criação de um campo data no cadastro do produto e este pode ser feito através do cadastro de um atributo referente.

Comment: Respondendo de forma mais direta, o atributo não fica visível somente no Admin.

Comment: Não tem campo texto e nem date nas opções de "Atributo" do prestashop. Imagem http://i.imgur.com/isqBvH7.png

Comment: Você deve cadastrar o atributo, depois de cadastrado voltar à listagem, clicar no mesmo a fim de "entrar" nele e depois cadastrar um novo valor para o mesmo (Editei a resposta a fim de mostrar imagem).

Comment: Qualquer dúvida posso deixar um pouco mais esclarecido.

Comment: Isso não serve para mim. Ao cadastro do produto tem que ter o campo. Veja essa imagem de como preciso http://i.imgur.com/caIYqHJ.png

Comment: O cliente ao visualizar acredito que seria indiferente, mas se você deseja que o campo seja nativo do prestashop (o que acho desnecessário, pois os atributos vieram para suprir esta necessidade), a principio você  deverá adicionar de forma manual à estrutura do prestashop este campo (programação + base de dados). Na pasta override é específica para você estender classes, onde seria indicado para este caso. Você deverá adicionar seja na parte admin como no front e nos tpl's correspondentes.